# Disabling React Native ScrollView scrollbar during scrollToEnd

Tags: react-native, android-scrollview

I'm using a ScrollView in my React Native App, and calling `scrollToEnd({animated: true})` within a  `useEffect`.

When its scrolling, the scroll bar temporarily appears. Is there some way to change that behavior, so that it doesn't appear, but is still there if I manually scroll?

Comment: have you tried `showsVerticalScrollIndicator`
 prop ?

Comment: @Kailash hmm, that disables it entirely, and I'd still like to have it for manual scroll. I suppose I could disable it, and then manually enable after the scroll animation ends (though I'm not sure if the animation duration is consistent/what the duration is)

Comment: We can declare 1 state for handling `showsVerticalScrollIndicator`. We will set it `false` before calling the `scrollToEnd` in `useEffect` and when the animation is finished we can again set the state to `true`.